Copyright page between title page and dedication in scrbook
How do I add a copyright page after the title page but before the dedication page?

Are you using \maketitle? If so, see \uppertitleback and \lowertitleback in the user manuals. If you have a problem with them, please show a minimal working example that can be used to reproduce your problem and that makes your question clearer. As an alternative to \maketitle you can use free designed title pages using titlepage environment or use a package like uni-titlepage.

Thank you @cabohah. \uppertitleback and \lowertitleback were what I needed.

I’m voting to close this question because a pointer in the comments solved the problem.

As section 3.7 “Document Titles” resp. “Dokumenttitel” in the KOMA-Script manuals explain, \maketitle in scrbook is not limited to the main title page of the document, but does provide a bunch of usual book title pages. The contents is defined using several commands:

\extratitle{…}
The first in-book title page is the mock title (aka fly-title or half-title). It is immediately below the cover and the fist page in the book block. The argument is free and can also contain paragraphs. It is printed top-down onto a right (odd) page.

\frontispiece{…}
The back of the mock title page. In early times it usually was a kind of decorative picture page. Meanwhile it is often either blank or used for a short copyright note. The argument is free and can also contain paragraphs. It is printed top-down.

\titlehead{…}, \subject{…}, \title{…}, \subtitle{…}, \author{…}, \date{…}, \publisher{…}
These are used to build the main title page. Each element has its own font, which can be changed using \setkomafont/\addtokomafont. However, the size of some elements are overwritten by hard coded sizes. See the manuals for more information about this.

\uppertitleback{…}, \lowertitleback{…}
These are used to build the back of the main title page. The argument of \uppertitleback is printed top aligned and the argument of \lowertitleback is printed bottom aligned. Note: Currently, if the height of both is greater than \textheight, the argument of \lowertitleback move to the next page usually resulting in an underfull \vbox warning.

\dedication{…}
The argument is printed on an extra right (odd) page. The font is also defined by a corresponding element and can be changes using \setkomafont/\addtokomafont.


Notes:

\extratitle{…} and \frontispiece{…} are a kind of pair. If both are unused resp. empty, \maketitle does also not output blank pages for them. So if you want a blank mock title page, use something like \extratitle{\mbox{}}.

\maketitle always prints the main title, even if none of the elements are defined. Some of them have defaults, resulting in warning messages, if they are unused. Some have other defaults.

The back sides of the mock title and the main title in twoside mode (default with scrbook) are always blank pages, if the corresponding commands are not used. They do not rely on option open (or the corresponding compatibility options).

The back side of the dedication page is always empty. AFAIK there isn't a command to change this.


The KOMA-Script manuals also show an example with almost the whole bunch of titles at the documentation of \dedication. In the following copy, I've just added an example of \frontispiece{…}:
% Example from the English KOMA-Script manual scrguide-en.pdf
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\extratitle{\textbf{\Huge In Love}}
\frontispiece{\vspace*{\fill}\par Copyright \textcopyright{} 2024 Me}% added (can also be used for other content like an image)
\title{In Love}
\author{Prince Ironheart}
\date{1412}
\lowertitleback{This poem book was set with%
the help of {\KOMAScript} and {\LaTeX}}% Feel free to add the copyright here.
\uppertitleback{Self-mockery Publishers}% Feel free to add the copyright here.
\dedication{To my treasured hazel-hen\\
in eternal love\\
from your dormouse.}
\maketitle
\end{document}

The example results in the following six pages:




So to fill the back of the main title page before the dedication page, just use either \uppertitleback{…} or \lowertitleback{…} as shown in the example. And yes, you can remove the \frontispiece{…} command after moving the copyright note to either \uppertitleback{…} or \lowertitleback{…}.
If you need instead a right (odd) page between the main title and the dedication, you should not use \dedication{…} for the dedication but define both, the extra page and the dedication free after using \maketitle, e.g.:
% Addaption of the example above with extra odd page before the dedication
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\begin{document}
\extratitle{\textbf{\Huge In Love}}
\frontispiece{\vspace*{\fill}\par Copyright \textcopyright{} 2024 Me}
\title{In Love}
\author{Prince Ironheart}
\date{1412}
\maketitle
\begin{titlepage}% Generate a new title page (odd page, empty style)
This poem book was set with
the help of {\KOMAScript} and {\LaTeX}

\vfill

Self-mockery Publishers
\end{titlepage}
\begin{titlepage}% Generate a new title page (odd page, empty style)
  \centering
  \usekomafont{dedication}{%
    To my treasured hazel-hen\\
    in eternal love\\
    from your dormouse.\par}
\end{titlepage}
Test
\end{document}

Needless to say: If you are not using \maketitle for any of the title pages, you can also simply add additional code between the freely defined main title and the freely defined dedication. So this answer concentrates on using \maketitle.

Use \uppertitleback, \lowertitleback and \dedication with \maketitle.

Maybe you could add a small code example that shows how to use these commands?

@JasperHabicht Done so in my answer above with small examples but long explanation.
